# android emulator does not work

Tags: android, android-emulator

I installed jdk 1.7.0, eclipse and the android plugin. I create a new android project but when I try to launch I get this message:

```
[2011-08-09 18:24:15 - myTEst] ------------------------------
[2011-08-09 18:24:15 - myTEst] Android Launch!
[2011-08-09 18:24:15 - myTEst] adb is running normally.
[2011-08-09 18:24:15 - myTEst] Performing crr.myTest.MyTEstActivity activity launch
[2011-08-09 18:24:15 - myTEst] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'myDev22'
[2011-08-09 18:24:15 - myTEst] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'myDev22'
[2011-08-09 18:24:15 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Files.
[2011-08-09 18:24:15 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-08-09 18:24:15 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

I get the same message if I try to launch the emulator from the sdk manager. What does that mean? Thanks, Andrea.

Comment: problem solved! I had to rename the path of the sdk in the 8+3 format, due to a bug in the current version of the sdk.

Comment: Can you move your solution down to an answer so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.