# make the android emulator work

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android emulator does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999595/android-emulator-does-not-work)

I cannot make my android emulator work, it gives me these error message.

[2011-08-20 15:17:03 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Files.
[2011-08-20 15:17:03 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-08-20 15:17:03 - Emulator] please use -help for more information

what can I do to make it work?

Comment: Did you add any AVD? (android virtual device) See here : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html

Comment: I suggest posting the command you ran. Also you might try http://superuser.com/ for this kind of question.

Comment: Is this on Windows? And have you installed it to something like C:\Program Files\Android SDK\? If so re-install it to a path with no spaces - C:\AndroidSDK\. This will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, because there is spaces in the path to your AVD, you need to run it using a batch file like this;

```
c:
cd c:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools
emulator -cpu-delay 0 -no-boot-anim -cache ./cache @my_avd
```

If your serious about deving for android however, I'd really recommend using a phone to debug, its like 4/5 times faster then the emulator....